# How to fix returning of the first value in a column instead of the appropriate value using VLOOKUP in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, match, vlookup

Good afternoon Please give advice.

In this screen, "C9" is a drop-down list of "A" values. "D9" is the result of the "VLOOKUP" function. In "E9" I need the index of the value "D9" from column "B". But the problem is that it always returns the first value in the column. As on a screenshot it should return "B6".

Is the a way of solving this problem? Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MP5Hr.png)

I tried this code:

=ADDRESS(MATCH(VLOOKUP(C9;A2:B6;2;FALSE);B1:B6;0);2;4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
="B"&xmatch(C9,A:A)
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thanks u a lot. Takes my hat off)